# my constructor method doesn't accept the arguments (directX/windows)

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, directx

So I have a construction method:

```
    SpriteSheet(wchar_t* filename, Graphics* gfx);
```

that takes an input (filename) and creates a texture out of it.
The problem is that when I try to use it like so:

```
sprites = new SpriteSheet(L"background.png", gfx);
```

intellisense underlines it and says:

```
no instance of constructor "SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet" matches the argument list
```

`argument types are const wchar_t [15], Graphics*`

I am following the guide step by step and I just can't figure out what is wrong.

It want's a wchar_t so I give it a wchar_t... I am lost and I really don't know what to do with this anymore. Please help.

Comment: `wchar_t*` should be `wchar_t const*`.

Comment: That solved the problem thank you very much. I've spent hours on this issue haha.

Comment: You absolutely must learn what "const correctness" means in C++, it is fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with const:
`SpriteSheet(const wchar_t* filename, Graphics* gfx);`

Comment: Note that in VS 2015 or later to meet C++ Standard Conformance, the compiler won't let you pass a literal string to a non-const function. The answer above is the correct "standard" way to do it and is the right choice, but you *can* also get older MSVC behavior by using ``/Zc:strictStrings-``. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx)